# Pass parameter to base layout route

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a React app using react-router and I am struggling with a simple feature. I have the following routes configured:

```
<Router history={hashHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={Layout}>
        <IndexRoute component={Home}></IndexRoute>
        <Route path="reports" name="reports" component={Reports}></Route>
        <Route path="help" name="help" component={Help}></Route>
    </Route>
</Router>
```

And my `Layout` component looks like:

```
<div class="content-wrapper">
    <section class="content-header">
        <h1>{this.props.title}</h1>
    </section>
    <section class="content" ref="content">
        <div class="content-pad">
            {this.props.children}
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

I would like to know how can I pass that `this.props.title` to be rendered in this `Layout` component.

I have tried the following:

1) In the route:

```
<Route path="reports" name="reports" component={Reports} title="Reports"></Route>
```

2) In the Link:

```
<Link to="reports" title="Reports"><span><i class="fa fa-file"></i> Reports</span></Link>
```

3) In the link with query param:

```
<Link to={{ pathname: 'help', query: { title: 'Help' } }}><span><i class="fa fa-question"></i> Help</span></Link>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where is the 'title' property supposed to be coming from? Is it going to be dynamic, or passed from a higher component? Or you're just gonna pass it in manually? Seems like the Layout component is the top level one

Comment: Exactly. The Layout is the "Container" for the other pages. The `title` property is to be passed to it so it can render the Title of the page it is rendering...

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<Route path="/" title="my awesome title" component={Layout}>
```

And in the Layout component:

```
<h1>{this.props.route.title}</h1>
```

Comment: Its working.. can be able to access the title in the child component by calling this.props.route.title